# Roblox (Luau): How do I force TextLabel text to update visually?

Tags: user-interface, luau, roblox-studio

Please see [this video capture](https://misc.miloonline.net/roblox/2024-02-04_textlabel_bad_update.mp4).

The `Text` field of the `Count` TextLabel shows the correct value of `2`, but in the view, the value shows a former value of `1`.  When I hover over the TextLabel with my mouse cursor, it updates to the correct value.

Looks like a bug to me.  Is there some way to force a graphical refresh when I change the `Text` value?

Comment: I suspect this happened because I was updating the GUI from a `Tween.Completed` callback (i.e. `Tween.Completed:Connect`).  Doing so from that context seems to be an unreliable means of updating a user-interface.  Instead, I'm waiting for the Tween to complete in the main thread, then updating my interface there.  This solves my problem.